# Ng build to multiple projects angular

Tags: angular, deployment, build, workspace

Hello I have a workspace in angular with two applications
app1 and app2.

My question is, how do you upload to the server? The two applications and workspace with the `package.json` configuration of workspace obviously.

When I have a single application, I upload the contents of the dist folder.

But now I don't know

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Angular CLI Workspace. then it's actually easy. If you have two or more projects. Example **app1**, **app2**.

To build app1

```
ng build --project app1  --prod
```

Your build will be stored in **dist/app1**. you can copy that to your server

To build app2

```
ng build --project app2  --prod
```

Your build will be stored in **dist/app2**. you can copy that to your server

**Bonus**
Add those lines to your **package.json** inside the **scripts** property

```
 {
  "name": "testapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build:app1": "ng build --project app1  --prod",
    "build:app2": "ng build --project app2  --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

Then you can run if you are using **npm**

```
npm run build:app1
```

or if you are using **yarn**

```
yarn build:app1
```

Comment: I understand but if i paste the content of app1 and content of dist/app2 app2 will replace app1 on the server or no?

Comment: This is not related to Angular. Where are you hosting your webapp

Comment: @RicardoEcheverríaOrtiz those are two separate apps, so yes app1 will replace app2 content. if you want to have multiple apps then just use subdomains. e.g app1.mydomain.com and app2.mydomain.com.